# PDF file in VB.NET (upgrade problem from VB 6)

Tags: vb.net, vb6, pdf-generation, upgrade, vb6-migration

I have upgraded my project from vb6 to VB.NET. The project is used to generate pdf files..
while upgrading I'm getting following problem.

Code:

> 'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Constant vbUnicode was
>   not upgraded. Click for more:
>   'ms-help://MS.VSCC.2003/commoner/redir/redirect.htm?keyword="vbup2070"'
>   'taptisColor = IIf(mvarEncodeASCII85,
>   ToASCII85(ImgColor), 
>   StrConv(System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(ImgColor),
>   vbUnicode))   sColor =
>   IIf(mvarEncodeASCII85,
>   ToASCII85(ImgColor),
>   DecodeString(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ImgColor)))
>   'sColor = IIf(mvarEncodeASCII85,
>   ToASCII85(ImgColor),
>   StrConv(System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(ImgColor),
>   VbStrConv.None))

The problem is that it displays a black coloured rect where it should display the image as logo.

Please help. What to do to resolve unicode upgrade problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621333/unicode-in-vb-net

Answer (score 3):

This Microsoft forum thread could help solve the issue:

[Upgrade VBA StrConv Byte Array vbUnicode ToString](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/ee8944c9-2207-4812-b5cb-17515ac82435)

Instead of `StrConv`, try to use the classes in the .NET namespace `System.Text.Encoding`.

Comment: It took me longer to reformat the question in order to make it readable to myself than to write the answer. ;-)